# using jdbi sql interfaces in dropwizard resource classes

Tags: java, sql, dropwizard

I have defined a resource class on a dropwizard project

```
@Path("/user/{user}")
@Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
public class UserResource {

    @GET
    @Path("/attribute/{attr_name}")
    public Attribute fetch(@PathParam("user") IntParam uid, @PathParam("attr_name") String attrName)
    {
        //TODO: write code here
    }

}
```

I want to use a sql interface here to do some sql queries on `uid` and `attrName`. The interfaces are in package `mypackage.api` which is a parallel package to resource package. 
How can I achieve those interface here.

Comment: Can you add the implementation of the interface to your `UserResource` constructor?

Comment: Import the interface into your class and call the method you wanted

Answer (score 2):

My dropwizard service uses jdbi to interact with a database layer.

The approach I used, (which is the fairly standard approach, and applies to your scenario) was to define the jdbi factory in the dropwizard Application class run method, e.g. (database configuration details goes in the yml config file - should be examples available online):

```
 final DBIFactory factory = new DBIFactory();
 final DBI jdbi = factory.build(environment, configuration.getDatabaseConfig(), "<your-database-name>");
```

Once you have access to the jdbi factory, you can instantiate your dao interfaces directly:

```
 final MyDao myDao = jdbi.onDemand(MyDao.class);
```

And as the guys above have mentioned in the question comments, you just need to pass the dao object into your resource, e.g. via the constructor:

```
 MyResource myResource = new MyResource(myDao);
```

Your dao should define function that accepts your resource parameters as 'bind' variables, which can then be used to lookup your data